# Clarification on various format specifiers in C program

Tags: c, size, format-specifiers

I am not understanding what is major difference between `%p`,`%u`,`%x`,`%d`, except that `%x` shows hexadecimal,`%u` is used for unsigned integer and that `%d` is for any integer. I am very much confused after I took a integer variable and printed its address and its value (positive integer) separately, then irrespective of whatever format specifier I use, it was correctly printing the output (except of the difference in hexadecimal and decimal number system). So what is a major difference?

And if there is not much difference then which format specifiers are preferable for printing what type of variables?

Another doubt is that: Whether pointer of all multiplicity (I mean `int *p;` `int **p;` `int ***p;` etc.) occupy the same size (which is the size needed to store a valid address in the machine)? If not, then what is the size of these pointers?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please go through the table at [printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, printf_s, fprintf_s, sprintf_s, snprintf_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) which describes all conversion specifications in detail.

Comment: Actually @pmg the size of a pointer is always `sizeof(char/int/... *)` because the pointer is a variable type. Setting `char` or `int` will just tell the computer that the step is one `char` or one `int` long.

Comment: Yes, those pointers all occupy the same size. However, this size depends on the platform and the hardware.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer: The C standard does not require pointers of different types to be the same size.

Comment: @Motun: in practice, pointers to data types will likely occupy the same platform-dependent size, but this is not mandated by the standard and shouldn't be considered portable. It's more common for pointers to functions to occupy a different platform-dependent size than data pointers, and you should never cast between data pointers and function pointers (nor cast from `void*` to a function pointer).

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in the same post. Post them as 2 different questions instead.

Comment: @Groo Right, I completely forgot about function pointers and especially some uncommon (once common) platforms with different pointer sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The `%u`, `%x`, `%d`, and `%p` format specifiers are used as follows:

- `%u`: expects an `unsigned int` as a parameter and prints it in decimal format.
- `%x`: expects an `unsigned int` as a parameter and prints it in hexadecimal format.
- `%d`: expects an `int` as a parameter and prints it in decimal format.
- `%p`: expects a `void *` as a parameter and prints it in an implementation defined way (typically as a hexadecimal number)

Additionally, `%u`, `%x`, `%d` can be prefixed with a length modifier:

- `l`: denotes a `long int` or `unsigned long int`
- `ll`: denotes a `long long int` or `unsigned long long int`
- `h`: denotes a `short int` or `unsigned short int`
- `hh`: denotes a `signed char` or `unsigned char`

Regarding pointer sizes, `int *`, `int **`, `int ***`, etc. are not required to be the same size, although on most implementations they will be.

Comment: In `[type] variable = malloc(the_size_you_want);` : when you use `char *` you define a pointer which has a step the size of a `char`. If you use `int *`, the same, but with a step of an int. With `char **` or `int **`, you define your pointer with a step the size of the corresponding pointer, but the inside variables are **not** initialized.

Comment: In which cases are the sizes of int*,int**,int***,etc. different?

Comment: @Crazyformaths I'm not aware of an implementation where they are different, however the C standard does not require them to be the same size so it's best not to assume they are.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why is int x = 3; printf("%u",&x); printf("%d",&x); printf("%x",&x); printf("%p",x); All of these commands are giving correct result(except for the number system).

Comment: These should not run because &x is a pointer and x is an integer, but %p expects pointer and others expect integer parameter.

Comment: @Crazyformaths Each of those cases invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the type of the parameter doesn't match the the format specifier.  Just because it appears to work doesn't mean it's valid.

Comment: But the decimal representations of all the numbers which are printed agree, don't that imply that this is the address of the variable which is actually printed?

Comment: On **your implementation**, pointers might be represented as simple integers in which case you'd get consistent results.  However, if you were to run the same code on a different system those statements might print different things.   One of the consequences of undefined behavior is that things may appear to "work".

Answer (score 0):

With format specifiers, you tell the computer how to interpret the given variable/data.

A quick demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = -5;
    printf("x value as int: [%d]\n", x);
    printf("x value as unsigned int: [%u]\n", x);
    printf("x value as hexadecimal: [%x]\n", x);
    printf("x value as pointer: [%p]\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x value as int: [-5]
x value as unsigned int: [4294967291]
x value as hexadecimal: [fffffffb]
x value as pointer: [0xfffffffb]
```

---

It's the same value given every time, i.e. `x = -5`.

- We see the exact representation when given the right format specifier (the first case).
- In second case we see a very big number. The answer to "Why" is a bit long to explain here, but you should look up how negative integers are represented in 2's complement system.
- In the third case we see the hexadecimal representation of the number `4294967291`. Hexadecimal numbers are usually shown with `0x` at the beginning but `%x` doesn't do that.
- The last one just shows how would the variable `x` seem if it were an address in the memory, again in hexadecimal format of course.